# Terraform apply throwing Error "timeout while waiting for plugin to start"

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, iaas, terraform0.12+

I am running into below error during terraform apply.

```
Error: timeout while waiting for plugin to start

Debug LOG:
2020-07-09T13:15:46.551-0400 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin process exited: path=/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-kubernetes_v1.11.3_x4 pid=48631
2020-07-09T13:15:46.551-0400 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin exited

2020-07-09T13:15:46.555-0400 [WARN]  plugin: plugin failed to exit gracefully
2020-07-09T13:15:46.558-0400 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin process exited: path=/.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-null_v2.1.2_x4 pid=48389
2020-07-09T13:15:46.558-0400 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin exited
```

Comment: Can you share the terraform code you are using?

Comment: If you're running that from within a docker container (as the `/.terraform` would imply), you'll want to be cautious about using alpine based images since they use musl rather than glibc, which drives golang binaries that are compiled with `CGO_ENABLED=1` crazy

Comment: @Rico Which files do you want me to share?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That might happen because the lack of resources on your system (e.g RAM).