# Why do I get "contents of zip are not valid UTF-8;" when using filebase64sha256 in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I am trying to create an AWS lambda function using Terraform, as specified [here](https://www.davidbegin.com/the-most-minimal-aws-lambda-function-with-python-terraform/):

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "dev" {
  role             = aws_iam_role.dev.arn
  handler          = var.handler
  runtime          = var.runtime
  filename         = "lambda.zip"
  function_name    = var.function_name
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(file("lambda.zip"))
}
```

But it throws an error:

```
Call to function "file" failed: contents of lambda.zip are not valid UTF-8; use the filebase64 function to obtain the Base64 encoded contents or the other file
│ functions (e.g. filemd5, filesha256) to obtain file hashing results instead.
```

I've also tried `"${base64sha256(file("lambda.zip"))}"` but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**All functions in Terraform starting with `file` take in the file path, not the contents.**

There are 2 issues here:

1. You're using `file` to read a binary file - it only accepts UTF-8 text
2. You're using `file` when that is already handled by `filebase64sha256` (the `file` prefix is the hint that this accepts a file path)

The [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/filebase64sha256.html) highlights both aspects:

> This is **similar to base64sha256(file(filename))**, but because **file accepts only UTF-8 text** it cannot be used to create hashes for binary files.

Remove the call to `file(...)` and it should work:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "dev" {
  role             = aws_iam_role.dev.arn
  handler          = var.handler
  runtime          = var.runtime
  filename         = "lambda.zip"
  function_name    = var.function_name
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("lambda.zip")
}
```